# Is possible to mapping view with class using mapper in SqlAlchemy?

Tags: python, python-2.7, orm, sqlalchemy

[As Mentioned here I created View.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766940/how-to-create-an-sql-view-with-sqlalchemy?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Is following possible to create view class for using with session?

```
v = Table('viewname', metadata, autoload=True)

class ViewName(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
       self.name = name

mapper(ViewName, v)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this, but you have to define a primary key manually. Assuming that `id` is a column of `v` which you want to use as the primary key (as is the case in my [original example code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9769411/92092)), this works:

```
from sqlalchemy import orm

class ViewName(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
       self.name = name

orm.mapper(ViewName, v, primary_key=[v.c.id])

Session = orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)
for r in Session().query(ViewName):
    print r.id, r.number
```

To test this, just paste this snippet at the end of my working example in the answer linked above. See [the documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapper_config.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper) for more details (e.g. you can use properties to define foreign keys).

*EDIT (van in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766940/how-to-create-an-sql-view-with-sqlalchemy/9769411?noredirect=1#comment30710842_9769411) to my answer linked above)*:
Alternatively, you can change the view definiton in my original code (and your question) slightly and write:

```
v = Table('viewname', metadata, Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True), autoload=True)
```

i.e., add the primary key in the table definition already. Then you don't need the `primary_key` argument in the `orm.mapper` and the rest of the code in your question works out of the box.

Comment: Apology for this. Correct me if I am wrong. I mixed your code and @van code. The following is works perfect for me. 
`class ViewName(Base):
     __table__ = Table( 'viewname', Base.metadata, Column('id',Integer, primary_key=True), autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)`

Comment: @SyedHabibM: yes, that works too. You just have to define the primary key somewhere.

Comment: How does this work in conjunction with create_all/drop_all? Currently drop_all fails since it tries to drop a table when it is in fact a view.

Comment: @fgblomqvist: I guess you want to drop the view, then? TProbably the best approach would be to extend `sql.ddl.SchemaDropper` to handle views. This would require some work because some of your views might have been reflected (ie you haven't created them and don't know they are views). As an alternative, a simple hack would be to add the corresponding `DropView` construct and drop the views manually before calling `drop_all` (which obviously somewhat defeats the purpose of `drop_all`). (...)

Comment: @fgblomqvist: (... continued) If you are only after views that you have created with `CreateView`, you could also extend `@compiles(DropTable)` to basically check whether it is one of your views and then call `compiler.visit_drop_view(element, **kw)`, and otherwise call `compiler.visit_drop_table(element, **kw)` (where  `visit_drop_view` has to be added by you). This said, you will find other cases where the view does not work like expected, because (doh) a view is not a table ;)

Comment: @stephan I did indeed end up extending `@compiles(DropTable)` and -- surprise surprise -- `visit_drop_view` already exists! But yeah, what I do is that I set an attr on the Table (is_view) and then check for that. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 24):

Finally I found it.

We can create class for sql view's. Here is simple example.

```
class ViewName(Base):
    __table__ = Table('viewname', Base.metadata,
        Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
        Column('foreign_key', Integer, ForeignKey('sometablename.id'),
            autoload=True, autoload_with=engine
        )
```

That's it. We can access "viewname" table using ViewName class.

Thank you for all who are respond me.