# Create view after all referenced tables are created

Tags: sqlalchemy

I need to create view based on multiple tables in SQLAlchemy. For view creation I'm using recipe from [How to create an SQL View with SQLAlchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766940/how-to-create-an-sql-view-with-sqlalchemy). Compiler extension is executed with execute_at as following:

```
def create_view_from_tables_A_and_B():
    CreateView(...).execute_at('after-create', TableA.__table__)
    DropView(...).execute_at('before-drop', TableA.__table__)
```

The problem is that between tables A and B is no relation and sometimes table A is created first, sometimes it's table B.

Is there a way how to run DDL after all needed tables/metadatas are created?