# How to create a view in SQLAlchemy ORM?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40083753/sqlalchemy-creating-view-with-orm) for another post says how to create a view. But all fields are generated dynamically:

```
class MyView(Base):
    __table__ = view
```

And after we query it as below:

```
engine.execute(select([func.count('*')], from_obj=MyView)).scalar()
```

Is it possible to declare a view fields obviously? To I could query it as other entities:

```
my_views = MyView.query().all()
print(my_views[0].some_field)
```

Comment: Have a look here: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/wiki/Views, if you want to define and create views from Python. If on the other hand you want to map an existing view, and define its columns explicitly in the mapping, just do so. A view is a relation just like a table is.

Comment: @IljaEverilä, thank you very much. It is that I wanted.