# Create sorted table in SQLAlchemy - ORM

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I have created User table:

```
class User(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.String(4), primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(100))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<User {self.id}>'
```

When I add two users like this:

```
u2 = User(id='u002', username='User2')
u1 = User(id='u001', username='User1')
db.session.add_all([u2, u1])
db.session.commit()
```

I want to have my table always sorted by `User.id`, despite the order I am adding new users. Is it possible to do this? I have only found a way to order `relationship`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally, some databases sort their indexes (like those for Primary Key) but that just maintains a reference to the actual record. However, there's no way to sort data *in* a table - unless you want to export all data, delete records and then re-create the table with the records in the right order.

What you probably want instead is for your *Views* to show the table data sorted. And that's where you should do it. See these answers for reference:

- [sqlalchemy creating VIEW with ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56205164/1431750)
- [How to create an SQL View with SQLAlchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9769411/1431750)