# Buiding a "pseudo-model" out of a query with sqlalchemy?

Tags: postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, json-api

So I already have a database defined in a specific way, and am building a JSON:API API around it probably using [Flask-REST-JSONAPI](https://github.com/miLibris/flask-rest-jsonapi).

The problem I am having is that some of the endpoints the API generates need to be significantly different to the database structure, and I don't want to build entirely new tables for lots of the same data because it's very dynamic and changing.

Can I build a complex query in sqlalchemy and then use that as a model? For a simple example if I need to join some tables, then filter the results, could I then turn that into a schema model to use with flask-rest-jsonapi?

If not (or if other solutions may be better suited) what other solution is there to this?

Comment: It sounds like you want to create a view or views?  Some examples at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766940/how-to-create-an-sql-view-with-sqlalchemy

Comment: @snakecharmerb views will not work because sqlalchemy only supports them as raw tables, not as models. flask-rest-jsonapi needs models. And you can't just build a model over a view, I tried, it wouldn't make sense because the view is missing things like relationship information.

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

Yes, you can use Flask-REST-JSONAPI.

## Longer answer

I think you are confused about the difference between "data layer" and "logical data extraction" in Flask-REST-JSONAPI.

- The "data layer" is an ORM of your database structure. You can't define something else.
- The "logical abstraction layer" can be identical to your data layer. This is the case you are describing. Also, it is the case in the [Quickstart](https://flask-rest-jsonapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) example. However, the logical abstraction layer can be very different from the data layer. To quote the [leading paragraph of logical abstraction layer in the documentation](https://flask-rest-jsonapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/logical_data_abstraction.html):

> The first thing to do in Flask-REST-JSONAPI is to create a logical data abstraction. This part of the api discribes schemas of resources exposed by the api that is not the exact mapping of the data architecture.

- Because you can define any relationship you want by defining a `Schema` with Marshmallow. It is hard to find a use case which can't be implemented with Marshmallow (though it may take a while until you figure it out...).
- Then you map the "data layer" and the "logical abstraction layer" with the resource manager. After that you can declare your endpoints.

Flask-REST-JSONAPI explains this really good in its [documentation](https://flask-rest-jsonapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (better than I did here).

---

## Other options

You can also use:

- [Connexion](https://connexion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/),
- [Flask-Restless](https://flask-restless.readthedocs.io/en/stable/),
- [RESTplus](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/),
- [Flask-Restplus](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Comment: Yes I understand all that already. But as far as I understand, with flask-rest-jsonapi when you get to defining the data layer, you only have the option of defining a single model to use (and relationships)? So even though I already have expressed what I want with marshmallow, I can't use it with flask-rest-jsonapi without building my entire own data layer from scratch and implementing pagination, filtering, etc again myself. Or moving all the database logic into the marshmallow schema.

Comment: Yes, all the logic is in the marshmallow schema. But maybe I don't understand your use case.

Comment: @above_level_c could you create a small example then that simply joins two tables and works properly with flask-rest-jsonapi?