# SqlAlchemy ORM __table__ using complex joins?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I've defined a model that represents the results of a SELECT statement that joins multiple tables together and performs calculations on the columns

```
from sqlalchemy import select

class ComplexModel(Base):
    __table__ = select([users_table.c.id, users_table.c.name, orders_table.c.total]).\
                 select_from(users_table.join(orders_table, users_table.c.id == orders_table.c.user_id))
```

and can use it like:

```
session.query(ComplexModel).filter(ComplexModel.name == "John").first()
```

How can I provide an interface that allows an IDE to detect the column names of a complex model is to define the columns as class-level attributes:

```
class ComplexModel:
    id = Column(Integer)
    name = Column(String)
    total = Column(Float)
```

errors:

`"Can't add additional column 'id' when specifying __table__"`

I tried using a [view](https://github.com/kvesteri/sqlalchemy-utils/blob/master/tests/test_views.py#L58):

same as above but:

```
__table__ = create_view(
        name="users-orders-view",
        selectable=select(...
```

But still:
`Can't add additional column 'id' when specifying __table__`

Comment: Instead of `SELECT` can you create this as an SQL view (depending on your database) - as I believe it might be able to solve the problem more neatly.

Comment: trying this: https://github.com/kvesteri/sqlalchemy-utils/blob/master/tests/test_views.py

Comment: I tried, still getting the same

Comment: I believe views are persistent in the database. So you creaet views by Alembic migrations or by hand. Then `__table__` is just the view name. I might be wrong though, but this is how I did it in the past.

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47514546/315168