# How to create a Union table inside the SQL database using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have the following structure :

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy.orm as orm

Base = orm.declarative_base()

class Equity(Base) :
    __tablename__ = 'equities'
        
    id = sa.Column(sa.String, primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.String, nullable=False)
    currency = sa.Column(sa.String, nullable=False)
    country = sa.Column(sa.String, nullable=False)
    sector = sa.Column(sa.String, nullable=True)
        
    def __repr__(self) :
        return f"Equity('Ticker: {self.id}', 'Name: {self.name}')"

class Bond(Base) :
    __tablename__ = 'bonds'
        
    id = sa.Column(sa.String, primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.String, nullable=False)
    country = sa.Column(sa.String, nullable=False)
    currency = sa.Column(sa.String, nullable=False)
    sector = sa.Column(sa.String, nullable=False)
            
    def __repr__(self) :
        return f"Bond('Ticker: {self.id}', 'Name: {self.name}')"
```

And I want to create a new permanent table inside the database that is the UNION of those two tables (using the columns ID and CURRENCY)

I know I can create that outside using this :

```
results = session.query(Equity.id, Equity.currency).union(session.query(Bond.id, Bond.currency))
```

But I want (if possible) to have a relationship table inside my Database that automatically updates when I change anything on either on the EQUITIES or BONDS table. Something like this :

```
class NewUnionTable(Base) :
    <relationship><union>
```

Can someone help me create this, please?
Appreciate very much

Comment: Sounds like you just need a VIEW which union's the two source tables? Then, anything that changes in either table is presented automatically by the view...

Comment: It might be that. I am still new to SQLAlchemy. I saw an extensive way to create a VIEW using SQLAlchemy here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766940/how-to-create-an-sql-view-with-sqlalchemy but if you have any simpler way, I'd appreciate it

Comment: There are many answers there, including references to the docs. If you don't find any of them useful, you're probably out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Views recipe](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/wiki/Views) and your classes (simplified), here is a functioning version of the view of the union of your sets of columns.

Read through the [recipe](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/wiki/Views) for more details, but simply it's creating the necessary compiler extensions and using them when appropriate via an event.

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, create_engine, event, inspect, select, table, union
from sqlalchemy.ext import compiler
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.schema import DDLElement


# boilerplate from https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/wiki/Views
class CreateView(DDLElement):
    def __init__(self, name, selectable):
        self.name = name
        self.selectable = selectable


class DropView(DDLElement):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


@compiler.compiles(CreateView)
def _create_view(element, compiler, **kw):
    return "CREATE VIEW %s AS %s" % (
        element.name,
        compiler.sql_compiler.process(element.selectable, literal_binds=True),
    )


@compiler.compiles(DropView)
def _drop_view(element, compiler, **kw):
    return "DROP VIEW %s" % (element.name)


def view_exists(ddl, target, connection, **kw):
    return ddl.name in inspect(connection).get_view_names()


def view_doesnt_exist(ddl, target, connection, **kw):
    return not view_exists(ddl, target, connection, **kw)


def view(name, metadata, selectable):
    t = table(name)

    t._columns._populate_separate_keys(
        col._make_proxy(t) for col in selectable.selected_columns
    )

    event.listen(
        metadata,
        "after_create",
        CreateView(name, selectable).execute_if(callable_=view_doesnt_exist),
    )
    event.listen(
        metadata,
        "before_drop",
        DropView(name).execute_if(callable_=view_exists),
    )
    return t


# demo
Base = declarative_base()


class Equity(Base):
    __tablename__ = "equities"

    id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    currency = Column(String, nullable=False)


class Bond(Base):
    __tablename__ = "bonds"

    id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    currency = Column(String, nullable=False)


common_view = view(
    "bonds_equities_union_view",
    Base.metadata,
    union(
        select(Equity.id.label("id"), Equity.currency.label("currency")),
        select(Bond.id.label("id"), Bond.currency.label("currency")),
    ),
)


engine = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True, future=True)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with Session(engine) as session:
    session.add_all(
        [
            Equity(id="AAA", currency="EUR"),
            Equity(id="AAB", currency="USD"),
            Bond(id="AAA", currency="EUR"),
            Equity(id="EEF", currency="GBP"),
        ]
    )
    session.commit()

with Session(engine) as session:
    results = session.execute(select(common_view)).all()

print(results)  # [('AAA', 'EUR'), ('AAB', 'USD'), ('EEF', 'GBP')]
```

**NB.** this is a [`union`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.union), so it's only distinct values. Notice four instances inserted but only three in the view. This deduplication (sort + filter) is slow on large datasets, if you do not care use a [`union_all`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.union_all) which allows duplicates.