# SQLAlchemy Core CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE AS

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use the PostgreSQL `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo AS SELECT...` query in SQLAlchemy Core. I've looked through the docs but don't see a way to do this.

I have a SQLA statement object. How do I create a temporary table from its results?

Comment: I found a post which accomplishes this using a custom Select class: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/sqlalchemy/O4M6srJYzk0/B8Umq9y08EoJ. The post is a year old; is this still the most idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: Apparently the `SELECT INTO` format, which is what my linked post uses, isn't the recommended way to do this in PostgreSQL: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-selectinto.html (see "Notes" section).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I came up with. Please tell me if this is the wrong way to do it.

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import Select
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles


class CreateTableAs(Select):
    """Create a CREATE TABLE AS SELECT ... statement."""

    def __init__(self, columns, new_table_name, is_temporary=False,
            on_commit_delete_rows=False, on_commit_drop=False, *arg, **kw):
        """By default the table sticks around after the transaction. You can
        change this behavior using the `on_commit_delete_rows` or
        `on_commit_drop` arguments.

        :param on_commit_delete_rows: All rows in the temporary table will be
        deleted at the end of each transaction block.
        :param on_commit_drop: The temporary table will be dropped at the end
        of the transaction block.
        """
        super(CreateTableAs, self).__init__(columns, *arg, **kw)

        self.is_temporary = is_temporary
        self.new_table_name = new_table_name
        self.on_commit_delete_rows = on_commit_delete_rows
        self.on_commit_drop = on_commit_drop


@compiles(CreateTableAs)
def s_create_table_as(element, compiler, **kw):
    """Compile the statement."""
    text = compiler.visit_select(element)
    spec = ['CREATE', 'TABLE', element.new_table_name, 'AS SELECT']

    if element.is_temporary:
        spec.insert(1, 'TEMPORARY')

    on_commit = None

    if element.on_commit_delete_rows:
        on_commit = 'ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS'
    elif element.on_commit_drop:
        on_commit = 'ON COMMIT DROP'

    if on_commit:
        spec.insert(len(spec)-1, on_commit)

    text = text.replace('SELECT', ' '.join(spec))
    return text
```

Comment: how does this compare to the `cloneTable` function in http://stackoverflow.com/a/9597404/656833 ?