# How to convert select_from object into a new table in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a database that contains two tables in the data, `cdr` and `mtr`. I want a join of the two based on columns `ego_id` and `alter_id`, and I want to output this into another table in the same database, complete with the column names, *without the use of* `pandas`.

Here's my current code:

```
mtr_table = Table('mtr', MetaData(), autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
print(mtr_table.columns.keys())

cdr_table = Table('cdr', MetaData(), autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
print(cdr_table.columns.keys())

query = db.select([cdr_table])
query = query.select_from(mtr_table.join(cdr_table,
        ((mtr_table.columns.ego_id == cdr_table.columns.ego_id) &
            (mtr_table.columns.alter_id == cdr_table.columns.alter_id))),
    )

results = connection.execute(query).fetchmany()
```

Currently, for my test code, what I do is to convert the results as a pandas dataframe and then put it back in the original SQL database:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=results[0].keys())
df.to_sql(...)
```

but I have two problems:

- loading everything into a pandas dataframe would require too much memory when I start working with the full database
- the columns names are (apparently) not included in `results` and would need to be accessed by `results[0].keys()`

I've checked this other [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30575111/how-to-create-a-new-table-from-select-statement-in-sqlalchemy) but it uses the ORM framework of sqlalchemy, which I unfortunately don't understand. If there's a simpler way to do this (like pandas' `to_sql`), I think this would be easier.

What's the easiest way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

So I found out how to do this via `CREATE TABLE AS`:

```
query = """
    CREATE TABLE mtr_cdr AS
    SELECT
        mtr.idx,cdr.*
    FROM mtr INNER JOIN cdr 
        ON (mtr.ego_id = cdr.ego_id AND mtr.alter_id = cdr.alter_id)""".format(new_table)


with engine.connect() as conn:
    conn.execute(query)
```

The query string seems to be highly sensitive to parentheses though. If I put a parentheses enclosing the whole `SELECT...FROM...` statement, it doesn't work.