# CREATE TABLE AS SELECT using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use SQLAlchemy to create a table from a SELECT clause as in the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS 
  SELECT foo, bar, baz
  FROM other_table
  WHERE foo > 50
```

I know that I can run a CREATE TABLE, then SELECT and finally INSERT, but this will ultimately be working with large quantities of data so bringing it into memory is not desirable. Equally I don't want to construct a text query and execute that.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30577608/16361)?

Comment: @AdamKG That could work. I'm still not 100% happy with that solution since it's still executing a string but it's definitely an improvement on an un-parameterised string and perhaps it is the best I can do right now.

Comment: Did you find any better solution?