# Combining 2 Tables to create a new table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have problem figuring out the SQL Script for the following :-

I have 2 tables -

[image: Job Charges Table]

[image: Model Hours Table]

and I would like to combine the 2 tables and create a new table like this: -

[image: New Tble]

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a new table from select statement in sqlalchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30575111/how-to-create-a-new-table-from-select-statement-in-sqlalchemy)

Comment: Post what you have tried so far and what is not working for you.  Also, in the future, please post sample data and expected results in text format.  It helps us help you when we can copy the data from your question which can't be done from an image.

Comment: Hint: it seems you are looking for a join.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Can you be more vague than "combine"? All we can tell is that you didn't use the Drelb-Furbisher Inversion to cromulate the finisters. An explanation of the algorithm you have in mind would help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this is to `CROSS JOIN` the tables and go from there. Let's create a script to experiment with your data to see what we get.

```
DECLARE @JobCharges AS TABLE (
    JobNo VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
    Column1 INT NOT NULL, 
    Column2 INT NOT NULL, 
    Column3 INT NOT NULL, 
    Column4 INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @JobCharges(JobNo,Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4)
VALUES
('Job01',10,20,0,50), ('Job02',60,0,70,100);

DECLARE @ModelHours AS TABLE(
    ColumnPos VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
    Model VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
    [Hours] DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @ModelHours(ColumnPos,Model,[Hours])
VALUES
('Column1', 'Toyota', 0.5), ('Column2', 'Nissan', 0.6), 
('Column3', 'Audi', 0.7), ('Column4', 'BMW', 0.8);

SELECT job.JobNo,
           job.Column1,
           job.Column2,
           job.Column3,
           job.Column4,
           hr.ColumnPos,
           hr.Model,
           hr.[Hours]
FROM @JobCharges AS job
CROSS JOIN @ModelHours AS hr;
```

The result of the `CROSS JOIN` is this:

| JobNo | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | ColumnPos | Model | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Job01 | 10 | 20 | 0 | 50 | Column1 | Toyota | 0.50 |
| Job01 | 10 | 20 | 0 | 50 | Column2 | Nissan | 0.60 |
| Job01 | 10 | 20 | 0 | 50 | Column3 | Audi | 0.70 |
| Job01 | 10 | 20 | 0 | 50 | Column4 | BMW | 0.80 |
| Job02 | 60 | 0 | 70 | 100 | Column1 | Toyota | 0.50 |
| Job02 | 60 | 0 | 70 | 100 | Column2 | Nissan | 0.60 |
| Job02 | 60 | 0 | 70 | 100 | Column3 | Audi | 0.70 |
| Job02 | 60 | 0 | 70 | 100 | Column4 | BMW | 0.80 |

When the data looks like this, it is easy to see how to get what you want. You can use the value of `ColumnPos` to choose which column you want to display. So I will set up a common table expression to use the `CROSS JOIN` as a subquery (you could just do a subquery if you wanted), and then use a `CASE` statement to choose the column value you want. Also, you seemed to ignore rows where `Charges` were zero, so I filtered those out with a `WHERE` clause.

```
;WITH crossJoin
AS (SELECT job.JobNo,
           job.Column1,
           job.Column2,
           job.Column3,
           job.Column4,
           hr.ColumnPos,
           hr.Model,
           hr.[Hours]
    FROM @JobCharges AS job
        CROSS JOIN @ModelHours AS hr)
SELECT crossJoin.JobNo,
       crossJoin.Model,
       CASE
           WHEN crossJoin.ColumnPos = 'Column1' THEN
               crossJoin.Column1
           WHEN crossJoin.ColumnPos = 'Column2' THEN
               crossJoin.Column2
           WHEN crossJoin.ColumnPos = 'Column3' THEN
               crossJoin.Column3
           ELSE
               crossJoin.Column4
       END AS [Charges],
       crossJoin.[Hours]
FROM crossJoin
WHERE CASE
          WHEN crossJoin.ColumnPos = 'Column1' THEN
              crossJoin.Column1
          WHEN crossJoin.ColumnPos = 'Column2' THEN
              crossJoin.Column2
          WHEN crossJoin.ColumnPos = 'Column3' THEN
              crossJoin.Column3
          ELSE
              crossJoin.Column4
      END > 0
ORDER BY crossJoin.JobNo;
```

The result of this query is what you want.

| JobNo | Model | Charges | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Job01 | Toyota | 10 | 0.50 |
| Job01 | Nissan | 20 | 0.60 |
| Job01 | BMW | 50 | 0.80 |
| Job02 | BMW | 100 | 0.80 |
| Job02 | Audi | 70 | 0.70 |
| Job02 | Toyota | 60 | 0.50 |