# How to Clone selected constraints in sqlalchemy table?

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

Inspired by [creating a temporary table from a query using sqlalchemy orm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593610/creating-a-temporary-table-from-a-query-using-sqlalchemy-orm) I had similar requirement but only needs PrimaryKey Constraint and want to add ForeinKeyConstraint based on new temp tables created.

I have added only foreign constraint by checking if the constraint is of type `PrimaryKeyConstraint` then add in constraints

```
constraints = [c.copy() for c in table.constraints if isinstance(c,PrimaryKeyConstraint)]
```

This is fine but I want to create a foreign key constraint on two newly created tables.
I have tried

```
constraints.append(ForeignKeyConstraint(['id'],['schema2.temp_table1.id']))
```

and as suggested added back to the table

```
 temp_table = Table(name, metadata, *(cols + constraints), schema=schema)
```

But it is taking a long time to create and insert the data. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Hard to tell without more information. My guess would be that inserting takes time because of the constraint checks. Can you try this: run your code without the `ForeignKeyConstraint`. If this is substantially faster, your problem is there. To solve it, you could do two things: 1) add the foreign key constraint only after you have inserted the initial data or 2) disable the triggers when initially inserting.